# GPU Utilization

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvml

I have been using NVML library to get the values of graphics and memory utilization for 
Rodinia benchmark suite. I observe that with different frequencies, the utilization of the same application shows different values. From the wiki link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_usage it seems it does not take into account the various stalls like memory, branch etc. What exactly is this utilization measuring during a time interval? And how come its value is varying with variation in frequency.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the utilization rates is given in the [nvml documentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML_cuda5/nvml.4.304.55.pdf), p90:

```
8.12 nvmlUtilization_t Struct Reference
#include <nvml.h>
Data Fields
• unsigned int gpu
Percent of time over the past second during which one or more kernels was executing on the GPU.
• unsigned int memory
Percent of time over the past second during which global (device) memory was being read or written.
```

The utilization rates for a given workload will likely vary if you change the application clocks (I assume that is what you mean by `frequency`).

For example, if the GPU core clock runs faster, then the processing of the workload may be changed, and it may take less time to complete the workload.