# per_process_gpu_memory_fraction does not work as expected in tensorflow r1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to limit the memory usage per gpu. As suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory), I do as following:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9))
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.log_root,
                         is_chief=True,
                         saver=saver,
                         summary_op=None,
                         save_summaries_secs=60,
                         save_model_secs=FLAGS.checkpoint_secs,
                         global_step=model.global_step)
sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(config=config)
```

But it still does not work (the `GPU-Util` of one of the GPUs has achieved to 100%). Could you please tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean usage? Could you show an example of your `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: @jkschin The `Volatile GPU-Util ` of one GPU is 100%

Comment: I think it's normal. See what `Volatile GPU-Util` means [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937894/nvidia-smi-volatile-gpu-utilization-explanation). You should look at `Memory Usage`.

Comment: @jkschin thanks for your correction. But it is weird. When the `Volatile GPU-Util` is 100%, `pool_allocator` runs quite slow.

Comment: P.S. It's actually simply `GPU-Util`. The Volatile belongs to something else. I don't know what slow means but all `GPU-Util` shows is how many % of your GPU kernels are running. If your kernels are an extremely complex operation, I won't be surprised to see 100%.

Comment: @jkschin After creating the device, tf do the pool allocation. And this step cost lots of time if there is 100 % `GPU-Util`

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937894/nvidia-smi-volatile-gpu-utilization-explanation?noredirect=1&lq=1) talks more about what `GPU-Util` actually means.

**Note that it's not `Volatile GPU-Util`. The `Volatile` actually belongs to `Volatile Uncorr. ECC`. `GPU-Util` actually exists on it's own.**

With regard to your question, seeing 100% `GPU-Util` is perfectly normal. To see if memory is being limited, you should really be looking at `Memory-Usage` and make an estimate of how much has been allocated.